# Broadcom BCM4352 Hotspot

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, 16.10, broadcom

I have an Asus PCE-AC56 which lspci lists as a Broadcom BCM4352 chipset:

```
Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

I would like to use it to create a wifi hotspot but iw doesn't show AP as a listed mode:

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
```

I am using the wl driver installed through bcmwl-kernel-source because, as far as I can tell, this chipset is not supported under the b43, b43legacy or brcmsmac driver.

Any chance there is a driver that supports both this chipset and ap mode? Ubuntu will let me configure a hotspot network, but when I connect to it to start it up, I get "Connection '..' is not available on the device ... at this time." which I assume is related to the lack of ap mode support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this card may be supported by a non-free binary driver from Broadcom, which can be installed from the broadcom-sta-dkms package.  In many cases this driver can enable AP mode, though it is not clear to me if it is supported on your specific chip.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunatey, after uninstalling bcmwl-kernel-source and installing broadcom-sta-dkms, anything that tries to use the network (chrome, iw, even typing sudo) immediately hangs when the wl module is loaded. Had to blacklist wl driver to get my machine to start. Same problem with building from source. Haven't figured out how to debug the hang yet.

Comment: That's unfortunate, sorry! I'd suggest purging the package then!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this：

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```